# Overwriting Table using spark dataframe fails when table already exists

Tags: python, postgresql, apache-spark, pyspark

I am attempting to completely overwrite a postgres table using a spark dataframe. For some reason, even when I specify `mode("overwrite")`, I get a `relation already exists` postgres error. Why isn't my code overwriting the data in the database like it is supposed to? I have checked the table using a client, and it DOES exist (which shouldn't matter). And there is data in it as well. What's wrong? Could this be a memory issue? Could it be the `queryTimeout`?s

```
    df.write.format('jdbc').options(
        url=PSQL_URL_SPARK,
        driver=SPARK_ENV['PSQL_DRIVER'],
        dbtable="schema.table",
        user=SPARK_ENV['PSQL_USER'],
        password=SPARK_ENV['PSQL_PASS'],
        batchsize=2000000,
        queryTimeout=690
    ).mode("overwrite").save()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hadoop/spark_script.py", line 671, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/hadoop/spark_script.py", line 83, in main
    ).mode("overwrite").save()
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 732, in save
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o352.save.
: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "<table>" already exists
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2468)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2211)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:309)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:446)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:370)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:311)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:297)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:274)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeUpdate(PgStatement.java:246)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.createTable(JdbcUtils.scala:859)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:271)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and the problem came from database schemas. Make sure that columns and types from the table in the database are the same as the dataframe.

You can write your dataframe in a new temporal table and use DESCRIBE in your sql engine to see the columns and types from both tables. You can try to overwrite again on the temporal table to see that it successfully write the data on existing table.

Another posibble issues is with permission. Check privileges for the user in the table:

```sql
SELECT grantee, privilege_type 
FROM information_schema.role_table_grants 
WHERE table_name='mytable';
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like the `mode("overwrite")` is the problem.  The problem is in `save()`, but it also seems odd that Spark is trying to create the table:

```
...
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.createTable(JdbcUtils.scala:859)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:45)
...
```

Are you specifying the table name correctly?  I wonder if it might be a Spark bug (I don't know enough about Spark to make a determination) -- maybe it's trying to create a table in `public.tablename` (because `schame.tablename` doesn't exist -- that's how I could conceive the bug manifesting itself), even though you specified `schema.tablename`

Comment: Looks like it might be the `queryTimeout ` actually, I increased it and now the job is running longer, although still stuck at the same `save()`. I wonder if I've overloaded my database?

Comment: We'll see--if it's still running at the moment, I wonder if it's just stuck at `at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)` or `at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)` -- both of which are called in the `save()` step (`at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:271)
`)

Comment: Not sure why spark chose to display this error, but the problem was `queryTimeout` being too small. I am writing a lot of records to a postgres table that has many indexes, and the operation takes a lot of time. After increasing `queryTimeout` I can now see the READ IOPS operations happening on the database